# Matrix similarity and diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I understand that two matrices $A$ and $B$ (in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n})$ are similar matrices if there exists an invertible matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (a change of basis matrix) such that $B = P^{-1}AP$.

My question is whether;

1. does a matrix $P$ always exists for any choice of $A$ and $B$;
2. and as such doest this imply that the $A$ is always diagonalizable;
3. is $B$ always a diagonal matrix;
4. in which cases does $P$ not exists?

I would really appreciate detailed answer to help me structure my understanding.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean does $P$ always exist for ANY choice of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I've updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Let me give an intuition. Two matrices are similar iff they represent same linear transformation. Therefore they must satisfy some properties which are connected to that transformation. Let $A,B$ two matrices and they represent $T:V\ to W$. If there is a $x \in V$ s.t. $Tx=8x$, then $8$ must be an eigenvalue of $A,B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. does a matrix $P$ always exists for any choice of $A$ and $B$?

No. For example, if $A$ is the zero matrix (all entries are zero), then $PAP^{-1} = 0$ for any $P$. So for any non-zero choice of $B$, there cannot be a $P$ which satisfies this equation. There are less trivial examples, but this gets the point across.

> 2. and as such doest this imply that the A is always diagonalizable?

This is (sort of) answered by question 1. Since not every two matrices are conjugate, it is not necessarily true that all matrices are diagonalizable. For example,
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} $$
is not diagonalizable (over $\Bbb{R}$). Its characteristic polynomial is $(1-\lambda)^2$, and so its only eigenvalue is $\lambda=1$. But you can check that it does not have two linearly independent eigenvectors (the only eigen-direction is $(1,0)$). If it were diagonalizable, it would need two linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$.

> 3. is B always a diagonal matrix?

No. The equation $B = PAP^{-1}$ is often used when talking about diagonalization, but the equation just by itself is just saying two matrices are conjugate.

> 4. In which cases does $P$ not exist?

This was answered in question #1.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. For instance, if $A$ is the identity matrix and if $B$ is the null matrix, no such matrix $P$ exists.
2. There are non-diagonalizable matrices, such as $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.
3. No.
4. When $A$ and $B$ are not similar (by definition).